# jsTree check_move Not Working

Tags: javascript, jstree

I need an event listener for BEFORE jsTree actually moves the node (and I need to be able to cancel the move). Right now I'm using the "move_node.jstree" event but by the time that event is called the node is already moved. I tried providing the following configuration:

```
        "plugins" : ["dnd", "crrm", "ui" ],
        "core" : {
          data : Mojo.Util.bind(this, this.__treeWantsData),
          check_callback: true,
          "load_open" : true,
          "themes" : {
            "icons": false
          }
        },
        "dnd" : {
          drop_check : function(){alert("drop check");}
        },
        "crrm" : {
          "move" : {
            "check_move" : function(){alert("check move");}
          }
        }
```

But the functions are never called. I'm using the latest version of jsTree (3.0.0-b).

Is there something here that I'm missing? Are these functions even supposed to work? The documentation says nothing about them.

If the move_node event provided the old position I could revert the move, but I don't have that so even reverting it is difficult.

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more or may be add your full code or try jsfiddle to show the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRRM Plugin is old 1.0 jsTree code. It is no longer supported in jsTree 3.0.0.
You are also using an old API for the DND Plugin. Please check the current versions API [here](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=dnd).